# QComboBox with custom model

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have a custom storage and I want to implement `ListModel` to display it with `QComboBox`. For simplicity let's assume that we have a list of `int` as a model's data, so here is my implementation of a model and test program:

```
#include <QApplication> 
#include <QDebug>
#include <QAbstractListModel>
#include <QComboBox>
#include <QHBoxLayout>
#include <QPushButton>

QList<int> list;

class MyModel : public QAbstractListModel
{
public:
    MyModel( QWidget* parent ):
        QAbstractListModel( parent )
    {}
    ~MyModel()
    {
        qDebug() << __FUNCTION__;
    }

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
    {
        if ( !index.isValid() )
            return QVariant();

        if ( ( role == Qt::DisplayRole ) && ( index.row() < list.size() ) )
            return QString::number( list.at( index.row() ) );

        return QVariant();
    }

    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const
    {
        Q_UNUSED( parent )
        return list.size();
    }
};

int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    QApplication app ( argc, argv );

    QWidget w;
    QHBoxLayout* l = new QHBoxLayout();

    QComboBox* c = new QComboBox( &w );
    c->setModel( new MyModel( c ) );
    l->addWidget( c );

    QPushButton* b = new QPushButton("+");
    QObject::connect( b, &QPushButton::clicked, [](){
        list.push_back( qrand() );
        qDebug() << list;
    } );
    l->addWidget( b );

    b = new QPushButton("-");
    QObject::connect( b, &QPushButton::clicked, [](){
        if ( !list.isEmpty() )
            list.pop_back();
        qDebug() << list;
    } );
    l->addWidget( b );
    w.setLayout( l );
    w.show();

    return app.exec ();
}
```

If I hit **button Add** only once and then check list, it looks okay, but when I hit it again, `QComboBox` displays only the first value and an empty line; continuing adding new elements has no effect at `QComboBox`.
If I click on **button Add** many times, then I can see the correct list in `ComboBox`.

I can't understand what is going on and what I do wrong.

I am using `Qt5.5.1` with `VS2013 x32` on `Windows 7`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your model needs to emit proper signals when the data actually changes. This is generally done by calling protected functions beginInsertRows, endInsertRows, etc... As these are protected, they can be called only by member functions inside `MyModel`. Also, for good practice, the actual data (your `list`) should be modified only by `MyModel`.

First, make `list` a private member of `MyModel`. It should not be accessed from the outside.

```
private:
    QList<int> list;
```

Add two public functions inside MyModel for managing `list`:

```
public:
    void push(int value)
    {
        beginInsertRows(list.size(), list.size());
        list.push_back(value);
        endInsertRows();
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if(list.size()>0)
        {
            beginRemoveRows(list.size()-1, list.size()-1);
            list.pop_back();
            endRemoveRows();
        }
    }
```

Inside main, keep a pointer on your model

```
MyModel * m = new MyModel(c);
```

Then use these functions inside `main()` instead of appending to `list` directly.

```
QObject::connect( b, &QPushButton::clicked, [m](){
        m->push(qrand());
    } );

QObject::connect( b, &QPushButton::clicked, [m](){
        m->pop();
    } );
```

Et voila

**Alternative, more Qt way**

Declare `push` and `pop` as `slots`:

```
public slots:
    void push()
    {
        beginInsertRows(list.size(), list.size());
        list.push_back(qrand());
        endInsertRows();
    }

    void pop()
    {
        if(list.size()>0)
        {
            beginRemoveRows(list.size()-1, list.size()-1);
            list.pop_back();
            endRemoveRows();
        }
    }
```

And connect them directly to push buttons in main:

```
QObject::connect( b, &QPushButton::clicked, m, &MyModel::push);

//...

QObject::connect( b, &QPushButton::clicked, m, &MyModel::pop);
```

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation! But the only problem that list given in my example is simplification of a real situation, and it could not be encapsulated in model, because it is already encapsulated by different class :-( Is there is any other way to nmotify model from the outside?

Comment: If you cannot call MyModel member functions right before and after data is modified, then it's not possible. You should change your program design so that the model class is responsible for handling the data, either by setting your other class as a member of MyModel, or by using multiple inheritance in your other class. The model architecture is no magic, it cannot detect content change in a simple memory container.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with this code is that model doesn't know that data inside list is changed. And the `QComboBox` doesn't know about data inside model changed too. So each time you change the data inside list your model should emit signals `layoutAboutToBeChanged()` and then `layoutChanged()` to notify `QComboBox` about changes.

Answer (score 0):

You have to implement additional functions, at least AbstractItemModel::insertRows. You have to notify a model about changes. For more information look into [docs](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractlistmodel.html).